# solana "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

Tags: solana, solana-py

Based on reading [https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L426][1]

It looks like the Token program does in fact have GetAccountDataSize so I am wondering why the fallowing code

```
def compile_transaction(owner_wallet: Keypair, instructions: list, latest_blockhash) -> VersionedTransaction:
    """
    compiles a simple msg and returns a versioned transaction
    """

    msg = MessageV0.try_compile(
        payer=owner_wallet.pubkey(),
        instructions=instructions,
        address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
        recent_blockhash=latest_blockhash
    )

    return VersionedTransaction(message=msg, keypairs=[owner_wallet])


def create_token_account(owner_wallet_path: str, mint_keypair_path: str):
    client = Client(CLIENT_ADDRESS)
    response = client.get_latest_blockhash()
    latest_blockhash = response.value.blockhash

    owner_wallet = get_keypair_from_file(owner_wallet_path)
    mint_keypair = get_keypair_from_file(mint_keypair_path)
    mint_pubkey = mint_keypair.pubkey()
    associated_token_address = get_associated_token_address(
        owner=owner_wallet.pubkey(),
        mint=mint_pubkey
    )
    print(f'associated_token_address: {associated_token_address}')
    # Check if the token account already exists
    account_info = client.get_account_info(associated_token_address)
    if account_info.value is not None:
        raise ValueError(f'Token account {associated_token_address} already exists')
    else:
        create_token_account_instruction = create_associated_token_account(owner_wallet.pubkey(), owner_wallet.pubkey(), mint_pubkey)

    # Create the InitializeAccount instruction
    initialize_account_instruction = initialize_account(
        InitializeAccountParams(
            account=associated_token_address,
            mint=mint_pubkey,
            owner=owner_wallet.pubkey(),
            program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
    )
    print(f'The token program is {TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}')
    print(f'The associated token program is {ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}')
    create_account_txn = compile_transaction(owner_wallet, [create_token_account_instruction, initialize_account_instruction], latest_blockhash)
    client.send_transaction(create_account_txn)
    print(f'Created token account {associated_token_address} for {owner_wallet.pubkey()}')
    write_associated_token_account_to_file(associated_token_address, owner_wallet_path)
    return associated_token_address
```

Generates the fallowing error message

```
solana.rpc.core.RPCException: SendTransactionPreflightFailureMessage { message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction", data: RpcSimulateTransactionResult(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, IncorrectProgramId)), logs: Some(["Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program log: Create", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 394486 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 6398 of 400000 compute units", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None })
```

This is on devnet